# How to write a string inside an array of .plist file

Tags: objective-c, ios9, objective-c++, info-plist

I'm new here. Hope someone can help me!

I'm creating a tweak in which I have AppList (Ryan Petrich) added and working, so I have in my preference bundle a linkcell with all applications and a switch on/off for each app.

When I switch some of them ON, it saves a `<key>ALvalue-com.some.app</key>` and a value `<true/>` in the preferences .plist.

I'm trying to figure out how can I change that structure of "key" "boolValue" to be like this:

AL-hd.plist file

```
<dict>
    <key>AL-hd</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.AppStore</string>
        <string>com.apple.gamecenter</string>
        <string>com.apple.stocks</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Instead of this

```
<dict>
    <key>ALvalue-com.apple.AppStore</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ALvalue-com.apple.gamecenter</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ALvalue-com.apple.stocks</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is my AppList .plist which saves the preference file AL-hd.plist:

```
    <dict>
        <key>cell</key>
        <string>PSLinkCell</string>
        <key>bundle</key>
        <string>AppList</string>
        <key>isController</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>label</key>
        <string>Show apps</string>
        <key>icon</key>
        <string>Favorites.png</string>
        <key>ALAllowsSelection</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>ALChangeNotification</key>
        <string>com.your.companyChanged</string>
        <key>ALSectionDescriptors</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>footer-title</key>
                <string>Check what apps you want to show up</string>
                <key>items</key>
                <array/>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>cell-class-name</key>
                <string>ALCheckCell</string>
                <key>icon-size</key>
                <string>29</string>
                <key>suppress-hidden-apps</key>
                <string>1</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>All Applications</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>ALSettingsKeyPrefix</key>
        <string>ALvalue-</string>
        <key>ALSettingsPath</key>
        <string>/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/AL-hd.plist</string>
    </dict>
```

I search a lot and try hundred of things.

Thanks!

One thing that I try was to create a second .plist and try later to copy that keys and paste it like a string in the second file. And to add a button in the preference bundle with this action in .mm file (with no luck):

```
- (void)save
{
    NSString *bundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];

    // Either this or whatever works from link after this
    NSString *prefPath = @"/User/Library/Preferences/com.your.company.plist";
    NSString *showPath = @"/User/Library/Preferences/AL-hd.plist";
    NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:prefPath];    
    NSMutableArray *show = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:showPath];    
    if ([[plistDict objectForKey:bundleID] boolValue]) {
          [Show addObject:bundleID];
    }
}
```

For me is not relevant if I use the preference bundle .plist or use a second one and then copy those lines in the way I need.

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. You need to at least show your code and explain how it works differently to what you require, then maybe someone can help you. Edit your question itself, don't try to add the material in comments.

Comment: You want to merge the 2 plist files into one?

Comment: No, I have edit the answer to be more clear... Sorry by my English!

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

1. Create a new .plist file and open as property list.
2. Click on + to create a new property inside information property list.
3. Name your property, eg-"Text" set type as "Array".
4. Inside the above created array add new item and for each item enter your text.
5. Now in your view controller class, you have to do this.

   ```
       //ViewController.h

       @property (nonatomic,strong)NSArray *plistDataArr;

      //ViewController.m


    -(NSArray*) plistDataArr
     {
       if(! _plistDataArr)
       {
         NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"YOUR Plist file name" ofType:@"plist"];
        _plistDataArr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
       }
     return _plistDataArr;

      }

     //viewDidLoad

     NSMutableArray *tempArr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self. _plistDataArr];
   ```

Comment: Thank u so much! But I don't have .m and .h files. Only .mm. I don't know yet how to change those files to .mm. This is happening to me, all examples I founded are like yours...

Comment: Plz upvote my answer, so that others could also take benefit.